# Why doesn't this node script filter the

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I'm writing a node script that is supposed to take a directory and an extension name as args, and log all of the files in that directory that end with that extension.  Sounds simple enough, but my script returns an empty array:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var ref = process.argv[2];
var extension = process.argv[3];
var files = [];
var dir = fs.readdir(ref, function(err, list){
    if (err) throw err;    
    var filterRx = new RegExp("\." + extension + "$");
    files = list.filter(function(val){
        return filterRx.test(val);
    });


});
console.log(files);
```

Can anyone help me understand why this isn't working as expected?

Edit: For example,
Given a directory with the following files (given by `console.log(list)` in the callback):

```
   "[ 'CHANGELOG.md',"                 !=    "LICENCE.md"                       
   "  'LICENCE.md',"                   !=    "README.md"                        
   "  'README.md',"                    !=    ""                                 
   "  'dat',"                          !=                                       
   "  'data.dat',"                     !=                                       
   "  'data.json',"                    !=                                       
   "  'learnyounode.dat',"             !=                                       
   "  'learnyounode.sql',"             !=                                       
   "  'learnyounode.txt',"             !=                                       
   "  'md',"                           !=                                       
   "  'w00t.dat',"                     !=                                       
   "  'w00t.txt',"                     !=                                       
   "  'words.dat',"                    !=                                       
   "  'wrrrrongdat' ]"
```

And passing the second argument `"md"`, I should get "CHANGELOG.md", "LICENSE.md", etc

I only get [] :/

Comment: Maybe you should check if your regex works properly, could you edit your question and maybe add an example of extension and file name  so we can help you further ?

Comment: @JoeClay there is nothing about asynchronous call here ? can you please justify your comment

Comment: @Nicolas: `fs.readdir` is asynchronous (as are most things by default in Node, hence all the callbacks). If you want to read a directory synchronously, you need to use `fs.readdirSync`.

Comment: @JoeClay Point made. Thanks.

Comment: @Nicolas: No problem, it's not hugely obvious at first glance!

Comment: @JoeClay  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Glad I could help :)